# how to log in Cytoscape

Tags: logging, find, out, cytoscape

To whom it may concern,

I am a researcher at the University of Minnesota.
I wonder if you could help me with how to log in to Cytoscape software.

Best regards,
Negin

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape doesn't have a login, per se.  You download an installation bundle and install it locally.  You can get the installers at www.cytoscape.org.

-- scooter